# How do i make a Laravel web.php route work on a new project?

Tags: php, laravel

sorry for my english.
I'm trying to create a laravel route but i just can't make it work.
My project name is "portalRAG". It's a web app. When i access "**my.address/PortalRAG**"
it works just fine, but i can't make any other route work.

This is a new Laravel Project. It's almost empty and i haven't touched any major configuration other than creating some 1 or 2 views,controllers and model and only created some html code.
Here's my web.php file:

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\ragController\ragHomeController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

/* NOT WORKING
Route::get('test', function () {
    return view('login');
});
 */

 Route::get('test','App\Http\Controllers\ragController\ragHomeController')->name('test');
```

I simply want to access "test" route. The controller i'm trying to use it's called **ragHomeController** and it's inside a **ragController** (a folder inside the basic Controller file).

Here's ragHomeController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\ragController;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ragModel\ragHomeModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ragHomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       echo("WHATEVER");
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ragModel\ragHomeModel  $ragHomeModel
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(ragHomeModel $ragHomeModel)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ragModel\ragHomeModel  $ragHomeModel
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(ragHomeModel $ragHomeModel)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\ragModel\ragHomeModel  $ragHomeModel
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, ragHomeModel $ragHomeModel)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ragModel\ragHomeModel  $ragHomeModel
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(ragHomeModel $ragHomeModel)
    {
        //
    }
    public function __invoke()
    {
    }
}
```

What i'm getting wront? i have tried clearing cache, clearing route cache, and nothing works.
How should i access my "test" route? (I have tried every way and i still can't make it work).
"**my.address/PortalRAG/test**"?
"**my.address/test**"?

Comment: What happens when you try to access the test route?

Comment: @aynber "404 NOT FOUND" no matter what.

Comment: instead of `'App\Http\Controllers\ragController\ragHomeController'`, try `ragHomeController::class`. Does the route appear when you run `php artisan r:l` ?

Comment: I think your issue is not how you are declaring the route, but that you have a misconfiguration on your web server. If your route was not successfuly registered, then you would get an exception, but you are getting a `404`

Comment: Ideally your project would have its own vhost and the url would be `PortalRAG.local` (or something). If you're inside your `PortalRAG` folder and run `php artisan serve` you can access the project via `localhost:8000` (I think) and your route via `localhost:8000/test`

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yeah the thing is, in the same server, i have multiple laravel projects and they all work 100% fine... I think it may be a Laravel config problem, maybe something i need to do on RouteServiceProvider or something?

Comment: I have never defined a laravel project inside a folder like you. I am not sure if you have to specify `APP_URL=https://my.domain/PortalRAG`, how do you have it defined? also, if you run `php artisan route:list`, what do you get back?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Bro at this point i'm start to think it may be a Laravel bug. I searched all over internet and nothing works. I even created another controller outside of the folder, and it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

please write you route like below

```
 Route::get('test',[ragHomeController::class,'Your_Method_Name'])->name('test');
```

and import your controller in top of your web

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ragHomeController;
```

Note:sometime it won't work so you have to run

```
php artisan optimize
```

if you are using xampp to run your laravel project then you can access your route like below

```
"my.address/PortalRAG/public/test"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done all the steps and it's still "NOT FOUND".
Think i'll go crazy lol.
Should i acces it using "my.address/test",right?

Comment: are you using xampp or you are runing PHP artisan serve?

Comment: Artisan server.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use the method that located in ragHomeController so write it in this way

```
Route::get('test',[App\Http\Controllers\ragController\ragHomeController::class, 'index'])->name('test');
```

now open your route like this:

[my.address/PortalRAG/test](https://my.address/PortalRAG/test)